# How to convert Bitmap to byte[,,] faster?

Tags: c#, winforms, image-processing, bitmap

I wrote function:

```
    public static byte[, ,] Bitmap2Byte(Bitmap image)
    {
        int h = image.Height;
        int w = image.Width;

        byte[, ,] result= new byte[w, h, 3];

        for (int i = 0; i < w; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < h; j++)
            {
                Color c= image.GetPixel(i, j);
                result[i, j, 0] = c.R;
                result[i, j, 1] = c.G;
                result[i, j, 2] = c.B;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

But it takes almost 6 seconds to convert 1800x1800 image. Can I do this faster?

**EDIT:**
OK, I found this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata.aspx
There is nice example. Only question I have is about `Marshal.Copy`. Can I make it copy data directly into `byte[,,]` ?

**EDIT 2:**
<s>OK, sometimes I got strange values of pixels and they do not seem to follow r0 g0 b0 r1 g1 b1 rule. Why?</s> Never mind. Figured it out.

**EDIT 3:**
Made it. 0,13s vs 5,35s :)

Comment: Try swapping the loops: you're currently iterating over the *columns* of the image, but bitmaps are stored in *rows*. Swapping the loops allow for better cache behavior, which *should* improve performance somewhat (although it's probably not by much).

Comment: You are correct. 5,65s before. 5,35s after.

Comment: @Miko: you might want to run that test again a few times. There really shouldn't be any difference between the two.

Comment: @MusiGenesis: While I can't eliminate the possibility that the difference shouldn't be detectable in *this case*, or perhaps usually in C#, I can assure you that the theory behind it is sound. It's related to the way the CPU cache works: it always stores blocks of X bytes, even when requesting less, so by iterating through the data in the order it's actually stored, the cache can be used more often. Sure, it's a micro-optimization, but it's one that doesn't hurt readability, and if you're looking for ways to make your code run faster, every bit helps.

Comment: @Miko: this is my fault for telling you to Google this, but don't use `Marshal.Copy` for this. See this answer instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740555/lockbits-performance-critical-code/858751#858751

Comment: @Miko: the linked answer shows how to access the pixel data using a byte pointer (and the unsafe tag). This lets you easily get at the individual bytes of the image and do whatever you want with them.

Comment: Where you able to copy this into a byte[,,] using marshal.copy

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can speed this up considerably by using a `BitmapData` object which is returned from `Bitmap.LockBits`.  Google "C# Bitmap LockBits" for a bunch of examples.

`GetPixel` is painfully, painfully slow, making it (ironically) completely unsuitable for the manipulation of individual pixels.

Comment: Yes, `GetPixel` is probably the slowest way to access a bitmap.

Comment: @Gabe: I disagree. The slowest way is to hand-write each pixel value on a piece of paper that you then mail to developers living in Siberia.

Comment: LockBits will give you an array of pixels which is [row 0][row 1][row 2]...[row nRows-1], where [row] is column length of pixels. Just remember the formula index = (j * rowLength) + i which gives you the offset of the pixel in the array of pixels. This also explains Michael's comment.

Comment: +1 yup, any non-trivial image manipulation in GDI+ pretty much requires raw memory access.

Comment: @MusiGenesis: Handing it to them personally would be much slower, than mailing it :)

Answer (score 1):

I've been wondering this for a while.

In .NET 4.0 Microsoft introduced the Parallel library. Basically what this does is there is a Parallel.For method that will automatically spawn off numerous threads to help with the work.
For instance if you originally had a For(int i =0;i<3;i++){ code...}, A parallel.For loop would probably create 3 threads and each thread would have a different value for i running through the inner code. So the best thing i can suggest is a Parallel.For loop with a

```
Color c
 lock(obraz) 
{
  c =  obraz.GetPixel(..)
}
...
```

when getting the pixel.

If you need any more explanation on parallelism I can't really assist you before you take some time to study it as it is a huge area of study.

Comment: Can you explain? I don't know anything about parallel loops.

Comment: @Miko: I wouldn't go there. Because of how Bitmaps work under the hood in .Net, parallelizing this process will probably make it even slower.

Comment: @MusiGenesis, actually I've done this in similar areas of image processing and the speed up was huge.

Comment: Getting a pointer to raw memory will be faster, so why complicate things?

Comment: @dko: parallelization would be a huge benefit for anything other than a .Net Bitmap and its GetPixel/SetPixel methods. The best solution would probably be to generate a BitmapData object from the Bitmap, and then manipulate the BitmapData in a parallel fashion. However, most of the performance improvement would come from just not using GetPixel in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried parallel `For`.
It doesn't work without `SyncLock` on the bitmap.
It says the object is in use.
So it pretty much just works, in serial lol... what a mess.

```
    For xx As Integer = 0 To 319
        pq.ForAll(Sub(yy)
                      Dim Depth = getDepthValue(Image, xx, yy) / 2047
                      Dim NewColor = Depth * 128
                      Dim Pixel = Color.FromArgb(NewColor, NewColor, NewColor)
                      SyncLock Bmp2
                          Bmp2.SetPixel(xx, yy, Pixel)
                      End SyncLock
                  End Sub)
    Next
```

In case you're wondering, this is converting kinect's `depth map -> bitmap`.
Kinect's depth range is from 11bit(0-2047) and represents distance not color.