# How can I copy byte[] into byte[,,]?

Tags: c#, winforms

This question is related to: [How to convert Bitmap to byte[,,] faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674317/how-to-convert-bitmap-to-byte-faster)
I have byte[] which has:
[r0, g0, b0, r1, g1, b1 ... ]
(r0 is the r-value of zeroth pixel and so on)
How can I copy this quickly into byte[,,]?
Or maybe I can get byte[,,] ditectly from `BitmapData`?

Comment: Your question in the other thread was already answered, so why are you still stuck on converting the image into a byte[,]?

Comment: And what are you going to do with the `byte[,,]` once you have it, that you can't do with the `byte[]`? Wouldn't you rather have, say, a `Color[,]`?

Comment: IMO the choice of a 3D array is a bad one. Indexing a 3D array is relatively slow, and for pixel manipulation that can matter. Personally I'd rather use one `byte[]` or `UInt32[]` and a helper array which gives me the line start indices. That's most likely faster.

Comment: I mean 3-dimensional array. byte[width, heigth, 3]. 3 is because there are three basic colors: red, green, blue. And I need it because it is easier for to write code that does something to picture if it is stored that way.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Color[,] is a bad choice. The Color struct has much more overhead than you want when manipulating images. Either define a 4 byte RawColor struct yourself(I did that in my project) or use a UInt32 as color.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: You say that indexing 3D array is slow... OK. What about byte[][][]?

Comment: @Karl: I like byte more than `Color` because if I used `Color` I wouldn't be able to modify it (object of `Color` class)  so every change to pixel would require creating a new object. That would not be fast.

Comment: @Code afaict Color is a value type, and the only real data is that which underlies the A/R/G/B properties; so why would there be significant overhead? Is going through properties that bad in C#? - Ah, I see; they're read-only. Yes, that gets in the way.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674394 - it's basically the same, but in reverse...

Comment: "What about byte[][][]?" - Bad idea, since it requires one allocation per pixel. `UInt32[][]` is a decent choice IMO.

Comment: @Miko `Color` is a struct, not a class. But it's about 16 bytes and not 4. This means an image takes 4 times as much RAM as it should. And will probably be much slower too. It has more data because it can deal with named and system colors. I noticed it in my project because the total RAM consumption was much higher than expected, and confirmed in Reflector.

Comment: @Code why exactly would you expect indexing into a `T[,,]` (doing math based on the array stride, and then indexing once) to be any slower than indexing into a `T[][]` (indexing, following a pointer and indexing again)? As for `UInt32`, you still have to do bit manipulation at the end to isolate components of the colour. Have you actually profiled this stuff somewhere?

Comment: You can have a look at the `Pixels` and `RawColor` structs I used. Pixels still uses a 2D array, instead of a 1D array, so you might want to adapt it. https://github.com/CodeInChaos/ChaosUtil/tree/master/Chaos.Image

Comment: I haven't profiled it myself, but I've seen several benchmarks indicating that jagged arrays are faster than solid 2D arrays. I'd guess the multiplication is expensive compared to dereferencing twice. On the issue of `byte` vs `UInt32` I'm a bit unsure. Both are likely viable. I used a struct per pixel because it was fitting my code better.

Comment: Why would "being able to deal with named and system colors" require additional space per-instance? It's just a bunch of methods and properties on a struct (i.e. not virtual), and static instances.

Comment: Dealing with system colors needs additional space because their RGBA representation can change at runtime because the user can change them in the control panel. But don't ask me why the overhead is as big as it is. IMO it could easily work with 8 bytes per pixel. But if you check it in reflector, it is that big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Martinho's answer but perhaps a bit faster(don't have time for benchmarking now):

```
struct BitmapDataAccessor
{
    private readonly byte[] data;
    private readonly int[] rowStarts;
    public readonly int Height;
    public readonly int Width;

    public BitmapDataAccessor(byte[] data, int width, int height)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.Height = height;
        this.Width = width;
        rowStarts = new int[height];
        for(int y=0;y<height;y++)
          rowStarts[y]=y*width;
    }

    public byte this[int x, int y, int color] // Maybe use an enum with Red = 0, Green = 1, and Blue = 2 members?
    {
        get { return data[(rowStarts[y] + x) *3 + color]; }
        set { data[(rowStarts[y] + x) *3 + color] = value; }
    }

    public byte[] Data
    {
        get { return data; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure how faster it will become by caching the multiplications, but it won't hurt for sure. +1.

Comment: `for(int y=0;y<rows;y++)` replace `rows` with `heigth`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's say you've got your data in a one-dimensional byte array. Do you really need to push it over into a three-dimensional array? If all you want is an easier way to access the pixel data, why don't you simply write such a simple interface to that array? Something along these lines:

```
class BitmapDataAccessor
{
    private readonly byte[] data;
    private readonly int rows;
    private readonly int columns;
    public BitmapDataAccessor(byte[] data, int rows, int columns)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.rows = rows;
        this.columns = columns;
    }

    public byte this[int row, int column, int color] // Maybe use an enum with Red = 0, Green = 1, and Blue = 2 members?
    {
        get { return data[(row * columns + column) * 3 + color]; }
        set { data[(row * columns + column) * 3 + color] = value; }
    }

    public byte[] Data
    {
        get { return data; }
    }
}
```

Comment: dang, you beat me to it ;)  LOL

Comment: @Miko: Guess my mental compiler is not perfect yet :) There's an extra closing parenthesis there! I fixed it here and in CodeInChaos' improved version as well.

Answer (score 0):

How about using something like this for ease of accessing the discrete bytes:

```
    class ByteIndexer
    {
        private readonly byte[] _bits;
        private readonly int _width;
        public ByteIndexer(byte[] bits, int width)
        {
            _bits = bits;
            _width = width;
        }
        public byte this[int x, int y, int c]
        { get { return _bits[(((_width * y) + x) * 3) + c]; } }
    }
```

You could even make it easier, overload this[] with:

```
        public Color this[int x, int y]
        { get { return Color.FromArgb(this[x,y,0], this[x,y,1], this[x,y,2]); }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider using the built-in `Bitmap` in `System.Drawing`. Here's an example with a 4x3 image.

```
var image = new byte[] {255,255,255,0,0,0,255,255,255,0,0,0,
                        255,255,255,0,0,0,255,127,255,0,0,0,
                        0,0,0,255,255,255,0,0,0,255,255,255};

Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(4, 3, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(
                        new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
                        ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);
Marshal.Copy(image, 0, bmpData.Scan0, image.Length);
bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);

var testPixel = bmp.GetPixel(2, 1);
```

testPixel will be a `System.Drawing.Color` set to `{Color [A=255, R=255, G=127, B=255]}`

Comment: I'm doin all of this to avoid using GetPixel